# Running Program on My Local Windows Server

Tags: php, windows, server, remote-desktop

I have a windows 2012 server that has been created for me. I am using a Mac and using Microsoft Remote Desktop to connect to the server. When I am using my Mac, I plug in the address of my server and code file (my_server/path_of_file) so I can run it but every time I get an error, usually either Server error 404 or Server error 500. How can I fix this so that I can browse files on my server from my Mac?

Comment: You probably have the IIS builtin web server. You need to install PHP on top of it (or install some other web server of your choice) and configure a web site. Sorry but this question is way too vague.

Comment: I installed PHP on top of it...is there anything else I could do that you know of?

Comment: Well... Don't care about remote connections from Mac until you configure things to work locally.